# Reusable flutter component (footer)

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a generic component `FooterMenu`  that is supposed to display items in the footer menu. The footer menu will be across the app and I would just like to include the FooterMenu component in a widget and pass the required menu items as a param.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FooterMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> menuItemsMap;
  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> navItems = [];

  FooterMenu({Key key, @required this.menuItemsMap}) : super(key: key) {
    this.buildNavItems();
  }

  void buildNavItems() {
    menuItemsMap.forEach((element) {
      navItems.add(BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: element['icon'],
        title: Text(element['text']),
      ));
    });
  }


  @override
  _FooterMenuState createState() => _FooterMenuState();
}

class _FooterMenuState extends State<FooterMenu> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _FooterMenuState(); //constructor

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: widget.navItems,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        // selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I now include it on a page that already has `build` method defined? Is it even possible?

Comment: What is preventing you from modifying the `build` method? Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by build method already defined? If you mean how you can include this custom BottomNavigationBar that you built yourself inside another page with a scaffold, just return the BottomNavigationBar and not the Scaffold with it, it's as simple as just doing this:

```
class _FooterMenuState extends State<FooterMenu> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _FooterMenuState(); //constructor

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
        items: widget.navItems,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        // selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
    );
  }
}



// Some Other class that you want to include your FooterMenu in
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    //other widgets
    bottomNavigationBar: FooterMenu(<Your argument menu items>),
  );
}
```